# File count in an HDFS directory

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

In Java code, I want to connect to a directory in HDFS, learn the number of files in that directory, get their names and want to read them. I can already read the files but I couldn't figure out how to count files in a directory and get file names like an ordinary directory.

In order to read I use DFSClient and open files into InputStream.

Comment: You can do recursively.

Comment: how can i do it recursively? @user2486495

Answer (score 58):

**count**

```
Usage: hadoop fs -count [-q] <paths>
```

Count the number of directories, files and bytes under the paths that match the specified file pattern. The output columns are:
DIR_COUNT, FILE_COUNT, CONTENT_SIZE FILE_NAME.

**The output columns with -q are:**
QUOTA, REMAINING_QUATA, SPACE_QUOTA, REMAINING_SPACE_QUOTA, DIR_COUNT, FILE_COUNT, CONTENT_SIZE, FILE_NAME.

**Example:**

```
hadoop fs -count hdfs://nn1.example.com/file1 hdfs://nn2.example.com/file2
hadoop fs -count -q hdfs://nn1.example.com/file1
```

**Exit Code:**

Returns 0 on success and -1 on error.

**You can just use the FileSystem and iterate over the files inside the path. Here is some example code**

```
int count = 0;
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(getConf());
boolean recursive = false;
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> ri = fs.listFiles(new Path("hdfs://my/path"), recursive);
while (ri.hasNext()){
    count++;
    ri.next();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention this in post, I want to do it in Java code.

Comment: Hello. Instead of posting two answers, you can simply edit the answer if it is not relevant and have one single answer instead. Multiple obsolete posts are not a good thing in the Stack-Exchange sites and usually get downvoted, flagged or removed. This answer fits this criteria. Please, consider either removing it or merging it with your other post.

Comment: One needs to be careful with getContentSummary#getFileCount() - the same used by hdfs dfs -count command:
It includes symbolic links into the count which may lead to an inaccurate number of files depending on what you need.
See https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/72003b19bf4c652b53625984d109542abd0cf20e/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/INode.java#L440

Answer (score 29):

**To do a quick and simple count, you can also try the following one-liner**:

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /path/to/your/directory/ | grep -E '^-' | wc -l
```

**Quick explanation**:

`grep -E '^-'` or `egrep '^-'`: Grep all files: Files start with '-' whereas folders start with 'd';

`wc -l`: line count.

Comment: This is the best answer by far

Answer (score 19):

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
Path pt = new Path("/path");
ContentSummary cs = fs.getContentSummary(pt);
long fileCount = cs.getFileCount();
```

Answer (score 3):

On command line, you can do it as below.

```
 hdfs dfs -ls $parentdirectory | awk '{system("hdfs dfs -count " $6) }'
```

Comment: Had to use $8 for the awk command, as $6 was grabbing the time (Probably just an HDFS version thing)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to check file count in that particular directory

`hadoop fs -count /directoryPath/* | print $2 | wc -l`

`count : counts the number of files, directories, and bytes under the path`

`print $2 : To print second column from the output`

`wc -l : To check the line count`

Comment: The question was about the Java API.

Comment: why do you use `*`? `hadoop fs -count /directoryPath` is not enough?

Answer (score 1):

**hadoop fs -du [-s] [-h] [-x] URI [URI ...]**

Displays sizes of files and directories contained in the given directory or the length of a file in case its just a file.

Options:

```
The -s option will result in an aggregate summary of file lengths being displayed, rather than the individual files. Without the -s option, calculation is done by going 1-level deep from the given path.
The -h option will format file sizes in a “human-readable” fashion (e.g 64.0m instead of 67108864)
The -x option will exclude snapshots from the result calculation. Without the -x option (default), the result is always calculated from all INodes, including all snapshots under the given path.
```

Comment: 5 years ago the file size was never a question.