# Count number of files with given extension on HDFS folder

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs

I'm writing a bash script that should be able to count the number of json files within a specified folder.

What I'm doing right now is this:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /path/to/files/*.json | grep -E '^-' | wc -l
```

When there is at least one file, it returns the number of results, but when there is no json file, I'd expect the result to be 0, since the path exists but it doesn't contain any files matching the `*.json` pattern.
What I'm getting however, is an error:

```
ls: `/path/to/files/*.json': No such file or directory
```

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Not an HDFS expert by any means but it looks like there's a tool to get the count directly. Piping `ls` to things is generally considered a bad idea. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20381510/2088135

Comment: @TomFenech the problem with hdfs dfs -count is that it won't let you filter by extension.

Comment: Hmm, that answer seems to suggest that it does but as I said, I'm no expert. If the only problem you're having is the case where zero files match, then the hack suggested in the answers might be sufficient. A slight improvement would be to remove the useless pipe to `wc -l` and just use `grep -c '^-'`

Answer (score 2):

Yeah , that is the default behaviour. Since these are error messages, they are sent to stderr not stdout.

In case you need to suppress the messages, you can use it like :-

```
hdfs dfs -ls  <hdfs_location>/*.json -R 2>/dev/null | grep -E '^-' | wc -l
```

(It would show only 0 (with no error) if no files with the matched extension is found ).

You can also refer : - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82698/how-to-mute-ls-command